# Comment prononce-t-on « je cherche » ?

Tags: prononciation

Je sais qu'avant les consonnes vocalisées, on assimile le mot *je* comme /ʒ/, et qu'avant les consonnes non vocalisées, on assimile le mot *je* comme /ʃ/

donc par exemple

- Je dis ---> /ʒdi/
- Je fais ---> /ʃfε/

Je sais aussi qu'il y a une exception si le mot *je* est avant un s, ensuite on dit /ʃ/ et on ne dit pas /ʃs/, donc

- Je sais ---> /ʃε/ et pas /ʃsε/

Donc j'ai deux questions : je pense qu'une exception similaire peut se produire avant le /ʃ/ écrit comme ch, donc est-ce que

- Je cherche ---> /ʃεrʃ/ ou /ʃʃεrʃ/ ou autre chose ?

Et aussi, qu'est-ce qui se produit avant le /ʒ/ écrit comme j, par exemple « Je joue... »

Je n'arrive pas à penser à un verbe qui commence avec /z/, mais s'il y en a un, j'aurais la même question (Wikipedia dit qu'on peut dire « Je zone »).

Clarification: je sais que quand on parle lors d'une situation formelle, on prononce toujours /jə/ dans ces contextes (sauf s'il y a d'autres règles de e muet, comme je ne te donne pas...). Ma question est seulement pour les situations informelles. (Ce n'est pas facile trouver de l'information bien pour parler dans situations informelles, donc cette page web est très utile ! Merci !).

Comment: Vous semblez prendre pour acquis que le **e** (**ə**) du **je** n'est jamais prononcé?

Comment: Non, c'est que je voudrais apprendre parler dans les situations informels et aussi situations formels (parce que je vive dans une région francophone, mais mon travail, c'est en anglais, mais j'aimerais trouver des amis ici).

Comment: (quand j'ai parlé en les etats-unis avec les etrangers que parlent anglais très formel, il y a des fois qu'ils semblent froids... je sais bien que c'est pas leur torte, mais j'ai peur que malgré ca j'ai une bias psychologique contre la langue formel. Je ne sais pas si je fais sens ou non !

Comment: Dans ce cas, ce que vous supposez dans vos exemples est plutôt adéquat pour les situations informelles. Pour les précisions demandées, elles sont dans ma réponse plus bas!

Comment: Pour les situation informelles, je recommande *Colloquial French Grammar: A Practical Guide* de Rodney Ball. Le Français est ma langue maternelle, et ce livre m’a fait découvrir beaucoup de règles que je ne connaissais pas, même si je les pratiquais d’instinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Je mets un bémol sur tout ce qui concernent la prononciation, car elle peut varier énormément d'une région du monde à l'autre (et même d'une région d'une province/d'un pays à l'autre).*

On prononce :

> *je cherche* ---> ʒə ʃɛʁʃə
>
> *je zone* ---> ʒə zonə

En langage correct, je n'arrive pas à penser à une situation où on peut ne pas prononcer le **e** (**ə**) du *je* (bien entendu, il y a le *j'* qu'il faut placer devant un verbe qui commence par une voyelle).

Ceci dit, vos exemples peuvent être appliqué à un langage familier.

Pour ce qui est de votre question en français familier :

> *je cherche* ---> ʃʃɛʁʃ *(ch'cherch)*
>
> *je joue* ---> ʒʒu *(j'jou)*
>
> *je zone* ---> ʒzon *(j'zon')*

Ajout:
Notez qu'il est aussi possible de légèrement prononcer un court **e** (**ə**) avant tout ça (ça aide à allonger les *ʃ* et les *ʒ* (enfin, c'est une tendance au Québec, je ne peux pas me prononcer pour les autres régions francophones du monde) :

> note : je n'ai pas trouvé le caractère **ə** avec le *brève*, donc considérez le **ĕ** comme un mélange de **ĕ** et **ə**
>
> *je cherche* ---> ĕʃʃɛʁʃ *(e'ch'cherch)*
>
> *je joue* ---> ĕʒʒu *(e'j'joue)*
>
> *je zone* ---> ĕʒzonə *(e'j'zone)*